# Moore Penrose Inverse for symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

Is there any proof that a MPI of symetric matrix is symmetric matrix?
Basically I need that Moore-Penroses invers of positive semidefinite matrix is positive semidefinite.
I can show that x^T(A+)x >=0. But A+ also need to be symmetric for positive semidefinite.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is this correct proof od this question?
A is symmetric so A=A^T, and denote MPI A+ with B.

Then: 
A=A^T
(ABA)=(ABA)^T           
A=(A)^T(B)^T(A)^T, since A=A^T         
A=A (B)^T A, so I wrote this with some other B, but B from Moore-Penroses invers is unique, so is this proof that B=B^T?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix and let $B$ be its pseudoinverse. By definition, this means that $B$ is the unique matrix satisfying:

1. $ABA=A$
2. $BAB=B$
3. $AB$ and $BA$ are symmetric

Taking transposes of these equations implies that:

1. $AB^TA=A$
2. $B^TAB^T=B^T$
3. $B^TA$ and $AB^T$ are symmetric

Thus $B^T$ is also a pseudoinverse for $A$. By uniqueness, it follows that $B$ is symmetric.